# boost spirit x3 match an end of lexeme?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

Let's suppose we need to parse "a" or "ab" inputs.

The following naive parser fails: `auto parser = 'a' | 'a' > 'b';`

One of the solution is to rewrite the parser to match the end of the input this way: `auto parser = 'a' >> eoi | 'a' > 'b'`

And it works fine.

But now suppose we need to parse a more complex input, like "a ab". And I'd like to reuse the old parser.

So I write `auto parser2 = lexeme[ parser ] > lexeme[ parser ]`

But `parser2` will fail to parse "a ab" since `eoi` isn't matched.

I know that an obvious solution is to rewrite the grammar ( like `'a' >> 'b' | 'a'` or `'a' >> -'b'` or somehow ). But I wonder if there is a way to match not only end of line but also an end of a lexeme?

Thank you in advance.